# Ruby application deployment symlink target location?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano, symlink

I'm attempting to deploy a very simple ruby (not rails) app using Capistrano on Site5 shared hosting, and so far my cap deploy:setup and cap deploy commands have succeeded so everything is deployed (I'm assuming) behind the public_html screen - so now I need a symlink to the relevant folder. I know this is the public folder of a deployed rails app, but what do I target for a deployed ruby app?

Thanks so much,
Becky